OxyPlot.SkiaSharp.Wpf zooming if using a touchscreen
I am using a PlotView from OxyPlot.SkiaSharp.Wpf in a WPF application running on a touchscreen device. How can I zoom?
I know that I can zoom with a mouse using the scroll wheel, +/- keys or using the middle mouse button (if available), but there is no mouse.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506674/how-do-i-implement-zoom-in-oxyploy-wpf this should help, just rebind the gesture to touch input as you need to
